# How to apply Onitem click using Java script

Tags: javascript, html

below is HTML page:

```
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="taxmanhomepage"  data-theme="e">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="e">
        <h4 align="center">Taxmann Demo App</h4>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
        <a data-role="button" onclick="callservice()">Webservice</a> 
        Todays Headlines:
        <div class="content-primary">
            <ul id="newlist" data-role="listview"  data-inset="true" data-filter-theme="e" data-divider-theme="e"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

and this is MY Java script code:

```
var URL="http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/mobileservice.aspx?service=corporatelaws";
var news_id=null;
var news_title=null;
var news_short_description=null;
var new_hash = {};
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {

}

function backToHome() {
    $.mobile.changePage('#taxmanhomepage', {
        reverse : false,
        changeHash : false
    });
}

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#newslistpage',function(event){
     $('#newlist').empty();
    });

function callservice(){

    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : URL,
        dataType : "json",
        cache : false,
        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            debugger;
        },

        success : function(response, status, xhr) {
            response=xhr.responseText;

            var responseArray = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(responseArray);
            var length = responseArray.length;
            var html='';
            for(i=0;i<length;i++)
            {
                news_id=$.trim(responseArray[i].news_id);
                news_title=$.trim(responseArray[i].news_title);
                news_short_description=$.trim(responseArray[i].news_short_description);
                new_hash[news_id]=[news_title,news_short_description];
                $("#newlist").append("<li 'style='font-size:10pt';'font-weight:bold';'><a href='#' ><h1 class='myHeader'>"+news_title+"</h1><br><h6 class='myHeader'>"+news_short_description+"</h6></a></li>");
            }
            $("#newlist").append("</ul>");
            $('#newlist').listview('refresh');

        }

    });
}
```

I am able to display it in Listview But I have to apply on item click mean and dsiplay  particular Item Id in Alert i mean to say that if we clcik on first Item it should display first item ID if we click in second or 3rd.....then it should display it ID. how i will do this am new in Java script

Comment: where is list item in given html?

Comment: first of all, if you google for tricks, use "javascript" to get rid of java code's

Comment: given JS has nothing to do with HTML. please paste you necessary code in http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: better http://jsbin.com

Comment: <div class="content-primary">
            <ul id="newlist" data-role="listview"  data-inset="true" data-filter-theme="e" data-divider-theme="e"></ul>
        </div>  this is lsitview item

Comment: This is only structure of `UL` where are `LI`'s data?

Comment: i have write seprte Js file and call that js file in its HTML

Comment: Using this code am Getting Out Put IN listview

Comment: so paste the final data. we can not get dynamic data likewise you are getting it.

Comment: http://codepaste.net/6ym3oo  See complete HTML code

Comment: yes i m Using crodva.js am getting Out put u please tell me how will display On item clci in ur Example

Comment: i LL convert that in MY crodava Phone gap