# How to get news_id in alert on item click

Tags: javascript, html, json

How to get item ID on item click, I am able to display data on in Listview i want to click on item show that i get particular `news_id` on alert.

This is my HTML page :

```
<body>
 <div data-role="page" id="taxmanhomepage"  data-theme="e">
  <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme="e">
   <h4 align="center">Taxmann Demo App</h4>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content" data-theme="e">
   <a data-role="button" onclick="callservice()">Webservice</a> 
   Todays Headlines:
   <div class="content-primary">
    <ul id="newlist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"data-filter-theme="e" data-divider-theme="e">
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

This is my JavaScript code:

```
var URL="http://www.taxmann.com/TaxmannWhatsnewService/mobileservice.aspx?service=corporatelaws";
var news_id=null;
var news_title=null;
var news_short_description=null;
var new_hash = {};
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {}

function backToHome() {
    $.mobile.changePage('#taxmanhomepage', {
        reverse : false,
        changeHash : false
    });
}

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#newslistpage',function(event){
  $('#newlist').empty();
});

function callservice(){
 $.ajax({
  type : "GET",
  url : URL,
  dataType : "json",
  cache : false,
  error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    debugger;
  },
  success : function(response, status, xhr) {
    response=xhr.responseText;
    var responseArray = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(responseArray);
    var length = responseArray.length;
    var html='';
    for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
     news_id=$.trim(responseArray[i].news_id);
     news_title=$.trim(responseArray[i].news_title);
     news_short_description=$.trim(responseArray[i].news_short_description);
     new_hash[news_id]=[news_title,news_short_description];
     $("#newlist").append("<li 'style='font-size:10pt';'font-weight:bold';' ><a href='#'  ><h1 class='myHeader'>"+news_title+"</h1><br><h6 class='myHeader'>"+news_short_description+"</h6></a></li>");
  }

  $("#newlist").append("</ul>");
  $('#newlist').listview('refresh');
  $('#newlist').children('li').on('click', function (){
   var index = $(this).index();
   //var text = $(this).text();
   alert(index);
  });
 }
 });  
}
```

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question [here?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16515225/1612146)

Comment: yes i asked But That was Bit different But now i m able to apply On item click function here question is how i will Get news_id On alert In Item click

Comment: remove the duplicate  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16515225/how-to-apply-onitem-click-using-java-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the append part in your code like this,

```
$("#newlist").append($("<li/>").data("newsId", news_id).html("<a href='#'  ><h1 class='myHeader'>" + news_title + "</h1><br/><h6 class='myHeader'>" + news_short_description + "</h6></a>"));
```

And change the click event like this,

```
$('#newlist').on('click', 'li',function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    //var text = $(this).text();
    alert($(this).data("newsId"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `news_id` as a `data-attribute` of the `li` item and then retrieve it:

```
$("#newlist").append("<li data-news-id='" + news_id + "' rest of string");

$('#newlist').children('li').on('click', function (){
     var news_id = $(this).attr('data-news-id');
     alert(news_id);
});
```

If you don't want the attribute visible then use `data()`:

```
$("<li rest of string").data('news_id', news_id).appendTo($('#newlist'));

$('#newlist').children('li').on('click', function (){
     var news_id = $(this).data('news_id');
     alert(news_id);
});
```

Comment: BUt i dont want to display News_id On Listview i have to display Only news_title and news_showrt Descriton

Comment: That's not what Konstantin pointed out ... read his answer. Test the code!

Comment: @user2372154 I have updated with a suggestion where the attribute is not visible.